# How do I embed IPython with working generator expressions?

Tags: python, embedding, ipython

Certain list comprehensions don't work properly when I embed IPython 0.10 as per the instructions. What's going on with my global namespace?

```
$ python
>>> import IPython.Shell
>>> IPython.Shell.IPShellEmbed()()
In [1]: def bar(): pass
   ...: 
In [2]: list(bar() for i in range(10))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/tmp/<ipython console> 

/tmp/<ipython console> in <generator expression>([outmost-iterable])

NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work, but IPython thinks it's the main program. So after instantiating IPShell, a crash shows "whoops, IPython crashed".

```
import IPython.Shell
ipshell = IPython.Shell.IPShell(argv=[], user_ns={'root':root})
ipshell.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are fine, this works:

```
[bar() for i in range(10)]
```

It's generator expressions (which is what you passed to that `list()` call) that are not fine:

```
gexpr = (bar() for i in range(10))
list(gexpr)
```

The difference: items in the list comprehension are evaluated at definition time. Items in the generator expression are evaluated when `next()` is called (e.g. through iteration when you pass it to `list()`), so it must keep a reference to the scope where it is defined. That scope reference seems to be incorrectly handled; most probably that's simply an IPython bug.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, I've found the following updates the scope so that `bar()` can be found:

```py
globals().update(locals())
```